# Bind9 getting out-of-zone warning on forward address

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, debian-squeeze

I've searched for hours after hours finding similar errors in almost all relevant forum sites on the web and none have helped me resolve my problem.

At the moment I'm running Debian 6.0.6 with Bind 9.7.3 installed and I get the following warnings in my /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 16 16:44:57 rikka named[6049]: /etc/bind/zones/unseen.horizon.db:16: ignoring out-of-zone data (nagisa.unseen.horizon)
Jan 16 16:44:57 rikka named[6049]: /etc/bind/zones/unseen.horizon.db:17: ignoring out-of-zone data (rikka.unseen.horizon)
Jan 16 16:44:57 rikka named[6049]: /etc/bind/zones/unseen.horizon.db:18: ignoring out-of-zone data (yuuta.unseen.horizon)
Jan 16 16:44:57 rikka named[6049]: zone unseen.horizon.db/IN: loaded serial 2013011613
```

Here's my forward file:

```
;; /etc/bind/zones/unseen.horizon.db - Forward lookup zone file for unseen.horizon
$TTL 2D
@               IN      SOA     rikka.unseen.horizon.   flaskis.unseen.horizon.  (
                        2013011613      ; Serial
                                8H      ; Refresh
                                2H      ; Retry
                                4W      ; Expire
                                2D )    ; TTL Negative Cache

@                       NS      rikka.unseen.horizon.

$ORIGIN unseen.horizon.

; @             IN      NS      rikka.unseen.horizon.
nagisa          IN      A       192.168.0.11
rikka           IN      A       192.168.0.100
yuuta           IN      A       192.168.0.10
```

And the reverse lookup file:

```
;; /etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa - Reverse lookup zone file for unseen.horizon
$TTL 2D
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN      SOA     rikka.unseen.horizon.   flaskis.unseen.horizon. (
                        2013011613      ; Serial
                                8H      ; Refresh
                                2H      ; Retry
                                4W      ; Expire
                                2D )    ; TTL Negative Cache

@       IN      NS      rikka.unseen.horizon.

10      IN      PTR     yuuta.unseen.horizon.
11      IN      PTR     nagisa.unseen.horizon.
100     IN      PTR     rikka.unseen.horizon.
```

And as requested I'll add my named.conf (or named.conf.local rather)

```
zone "unseen.horizon.db" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/unseen.horizon.db";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

Am I missing something? I'm at a bind here (pun not intended) and I would really appreciate some help on this matter.

Comment: can you add your named.conf for this domain?

Comment: Can you add the `zone "..." { ... }` section from your named.conf file?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, forgot about that one. It's added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you are...  just change:

```
zone "unseen.horizon.db" IN {
```

To

```
zone "unseen.horizon" IN {
```

Comment: Wow, it's always the simple stuff that you miss, thanks!

Now I just need to find out why host and host -l on my domain only gives me NXDOMAIN and NOTAUTH, but that I'll seek help on when I've given up on solving it too ;)